# Django: How to only display content made by a user to that same user?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-database

I'm learning Django (obviously) and one thing I just noticed about a project I'm building is that initially, Each user could see objects/content made by every other user. For instance, my project is a very basic fantasy football app, I've set it up so that a user can create a team by adding listed players to my team model called "MyTeam" as seen here.

```
class Myteam(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    QB = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    QBscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    RB1 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    RB1score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    RB2 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    RB2score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    WR = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    WR1score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    WR2 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    WR2score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    TE = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    TEscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    D = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    Dscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    K = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    Kscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

I've learned about ForeignKeys for linking specific content to a particular user and the next step I'm trying to figure out is how to get it so that a logged-in user can only see their team and no one else's. I've been searching around here and other places via google, but as a Django noob, it's hard to even verbalize the right question to search for in the first place.

I thought I was on the right track when I saw somewhere that I might need to filter the content being returned in my views.py. Here's something I tried earlier that didn't work.

```
def index(request):
    
    team = Myteam.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
```

This always returns an error of...

> Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: D, Dscore, K, Kscore, QB, QBscore, RB1, RB1score, RB2, RB2score, TE, TEscore, WR, WR1score, WR2, WR2score, author, author_id, id

previously, my code in views.py > def index was

```
def index(request):
    
    team = Myteam.objects.get()
```

This was obviously getting all objects in the database. I understand I need to filter out by user, but I'm just not quite sure how to get that working. I appreciate your time and attention if you look at this.

This is my user class.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
import datetime



class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Here is login.html

```
{% extends "game/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2>Login</h2>

        {% if message %}
            <div>{{ message }}</div>
        {% endif %}

        <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autofocus class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
        <br>
        Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register here.</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If you're querying `author=request.user.id` why is the stacktrace saying that: `Cannot resolve keyword 'USER' into field.` ?

You're not copying the result of `Myteam.objects.filter(author=request.user.id)`, but something else, probably you wrote `Myteam.objects.filter(USER=request.user.id)` in your code.

Comment: Actually. you're right. I pasted the wrong example query. It should say team = Myteam.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your view this way

```
def index(request):

    team = Myteam.objects.filter(author=request.user).first()
```

or

```
def index(request):

    team = Myteam.objects.filter(author_id=request.user.id).first()
```

Comment: Gives me an AttributeError 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'QB'

Comment: I'm just reporting back what happens when I try it out.

Comment: Aha! That works. Thanks so much for your help. When I log out though it's also returning an AttributError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'QB' instead of just going to the index url. Do you think it's related to this change?

Comment: That happens when there is no team related to the user, because the queryset returns None in that case. You need to handle that creating the related team or sending a 404 to the user. It depends on your app logic.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Reading up on this now.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing id to a name field.

**Here: author refers to a user field**.

If you want to get that related team for that User, Do like this

```
team = Myteam.objects.filter(author_id=request.user.id)

or

team = Myteam.objects.filter(author=request.user)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's simple...

Get your `User` model first.

```
from YourUserApp.model import User
```

Then, get your User like below:

```
def index(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
    team = Myteam.objects.filter(author=user)
```

Done...

You can use your own credentials if you don't have `username or password`.

Can you please paste your `User` model?

Use this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
team = Myteam.objects.filter(author=user)
```

If `user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)` doesn't work then use `user=request.user` or `author_id=request.user.id`